# Can prometheus don't resolve alert when metric data missing?

Tags: prometheus

There is my Prometheus alert rule

`avg_over_time(metricName[1m]) > 100`

After alert fired, when the metrci data missing for more than 1 minute, the alert will resolved.

Is there any way to stop the change of alert status?

Comment: i believe the option does not exist as the idea is to base the alert on a metric.
as far as i see it you have two options.
1. increase the range of the query from 1m to more so that incase you are missing metrics for a minnuet it will not affect you or you can use tha absent function wich returns 1 when there is no metric.

Comment: Option 1 is the best way I can find now, But it is not friendly for the user who doesn't understand proemetheus when they receive the alert message.  Option 2 can let promethues don't trigger alert when data missing,but the alert will still be resolved when the data missing.

Comment: If promethues support set another rule to control when to resolve the alert, this problem can be solved.

Comment: i think you can make the alert clearer by explaining in the alert description what it represents then the receiver should not really car how you calculated the alert.

i do not believe you can use an alert to resolve a different alert.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by leveraging last_over_time() as in my [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69583854/prometheus-no-metric-clears-alert).

(Answering this old question because it's still a high ranking Google result)