# Prometheus no metric clears alert

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

We use Prometheus to watch metrics of our own application. The API of our application offers an endpoint to deliver the metrics to Prometheus. Prometheus is scraping the information every 30s.

Based on the metrics we defined some alerts, which are firing to Alertmanager and then trigger email alerting, Slack messages or are shown in Alerta.

From time to time our application can't deliver the metrics and the Prometheus scraper is running in a timeout. Whenever a metric is missing in such a moment, the corresponding alert gets cleared (within Email, Slack, Alerta).

After 30sec our application delivers metrics again and a new alert is raised by Prometheus (which again triggers Emails, Slack messages and shows up a new alert in Alerta).

A missing metric is no reason to clear out an alert if no metric is given, on which the clearance of an alert might be based on (at least in our opinion).

Is there any option to configure Prometheus or Alertmanager in a way, that an alert is only solved/cleared if a metric leads to that (instead of interpreting the lack of metric as a clearance of an alert)?

Comment: What do you mean by 'the metric leads to that'? Prometheus doesn't have an option to inverse the expr the determine the state. It simply considers the results as the alerts, so no results = no alert

Answer (score 5):

This can be done by using the aggregation function [last_over_time()](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#aggregation_over_time).

For example, say your metric of interest is: `probe_success`

And your alert expression currently is: `probe_success == 0`

This will return no value if the metric is absent, and thus your alert clears creating the issue you described.

Instead change your alert expression to: `last_over_time(probe_success[12h]) == 0`

That will instead return the last metric value that was recorded in the past 12 hours.  Adjust the time range to however long you are willing to tolerate that metric being absent while still assuming it will return.

Comment: This could solve this problem but if this happens a lot like in this case metrics will not be scraped for an app instance, it can affect multiple metrics, meaning we have to add last_over_time for every metrics that affected, is there a better way to tolerate this globally ? will a longer `evaluation_interval`  fix this?